# Opinions about opinions (of a plot)

Tags: discussion

OK, this is going to be a fairly ironic question (I think, I've always had trouble with what is real irony), and is a request for some sort of consensus of users to decide on a (possible) change of topicality that would set Movies & TV SE separate from almost all other Stacks.

**TL:DR**
I need to ask your opinion about opinions... see?

Alright, the question "[Who caught the last touchdown pass in the series finale of Friday Night Lights?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/115880/who-caught-the-last-touchdown-pass-in-the-series-finale-of-friday-night-lights)" came up in my reopen queue. The question is currently closed, with the shown reason of:

> Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.
> Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question.
>
> Closed 4 days ago by Spectra, mattiav27, BCdotWEB, Joachim, Paulie_D.
>
> The community is reviewing whether to reopen this question as of 3 days ago.

In the comments, the author ( @blankip ) [asked](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/115880/timeline#comment_199823):

> Can someone please tell me why this question is closed? It for sure does not need clarity or details. Looks like mod just randomly has no idea what they are talking about and closes question. Good job!

@user10191234 [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/115880/timeline#comment_199845):

> I might be wrong but because you are asking something that could be interpreted as a trivia for a show that (sadly) ended a decade ago.

It was at that point that I saw it in my reopen queue. I did some research, looking for any indication from a person actually part of the [Friday Night Lights TV Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_Night_Lights_(TV_series)). Perhaps an actor, perhaps director, maybe even the showrunner. I didn't happen to find one stating who caught the pass. Remember, this series was aired originally from 2006-2011, a decade ago. Of course, it still is watchable via various means (DVDs, Netflix, CBS, etc).

Because I didn't find anything doesn't necessarily mean there wasn't something, but it's very hard to prove a negative. So, I agreed with the idea that it is "unanswerable trivia". Now, personally, I don't like to do stuff in SE without explanation. We may not be required to explain a up- or down-vote, but not doing so doesn't really help the user.

If I VtC, I try to always put the reason I did in a comment. This has caused more issues that I care to relate. Quite often the OP will disagree with my comment and post a rebuttal, which of course starts a commentary dialog. In this case, I didn't actually DO a thing, but DIDN'T do a think (I didn't VtRO). I still gave a reason (I agreed that it is unanswerable trivia).

Now, of course, blankip disagreed with me, as so many have, and he [wrote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/115880/timeline#comment_199892):

> then 80% of the questions are trivia according to you. It is not trivia. If it were trivia it would have an easy answer.

But then he also [wrote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/115880/timeline#comment_199894):

> and how do you assume you are the smartest person in the world and if you think it is unknown it must be? Don't you think others may have differing viewpoints?

...

"Don't you think others may have differing viewpoints?" Yes, I do. However, this is explicitly stating that the *actual reason he posted the question* was to gather other opinions on what people/viewers felt, believed, wished that final scene represented. As we all know, questions which ask for opinions are explicitly off-topic on (almost?) all Stacks. They a asking for multiple answers, none of which are provably correct, and then the OP would presumable pick the opinion which most closely represents their own view.

This degenerates a question to a forum-like discussion, and like I said, is off-topic.

In our own help center, in the *what questions should I avoid asking* section (which is still the standard form, I think), there are two parts that are relevant:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

and

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references

So, after reams of rambling, here's what I want to ask:
**Do we want to allow, as a community, questions which ask opinions about plots, where there is no confirmable answer by an expert (showrunner, director, producer, actor)?**

<sub>(I do apologize for the rambling and sucky formatting, I'm not actually good at this. Feel free to clean it up if you wish.)</sub>

Comment: I agree with most of this but I just rebutted not rebutted fully.   I still think there could be some authoritative answer from some director/producer interview or someone that has broken down the show and zoomed in on something normal viewers wouldn't see (zoom in on a newspaper clipping, example).   I have to admit compared to other SE sites I use, I find this one kind of annoying as the rules are arbitrarily set based on the top 10 users like/dislikes.   It leaves a negative taste in your mouth and you don't want to come back.

Comment: ...cont...   And it is super annoying that these users close it for "needs clarity" when it ABSOLUTELY DOESN'T.   In a perfect world the users that voted to close based on that should lose their ability to close things for a week or two.   You are basically saying I am lazy writing my question, but they were wrong and were actually lazy giving a close reason.    If the close reason were "this is trivia" I could have added a few sentences to my question.   But honestly anyone who could answer this, knows its not trivia.

Comment: Another way to go through a question like this is I start going through the site and voting to close out every question that is "as trivia as mine".   That would be a good cleanse of 30-40% of the questions at least.

Comment: There seems about a ton of various different things wrong with that question and it's a bit unclear for what specific reason specific users closed it, primarily because the question is *extremely* terse about its topic and what it's actually asking for. That's probably why it was closed as "unclear". This makes this meta question laden with a variety of different issues and even the one you picked isn't answerable easily. Of course we don't just do opinions about what you wish happened in the story. But we definitely encourage discussion beyond simple director interviews or Wiki quotes.

Comment: @blankip *"Another way to go through a question like this is I start going through the site and voting to close out every question that is "as trivia as mine". That would be a good cleanse of 30-40% of the questions at least."* - I'm afraid it wouldn't, because that could quickly lead to a suspension for close-vote abuse instead.

Comment: If my question is trivia then I could do exactly as I said within the guidelines of the site you mod.   So you would be suspending me for trying to enforce the guidelines you want?   I am flagging both of your comments - because they are not nice, threatening and in general making a user feel beneath you.

Comment: @blankip On SE we really don't take kindly to people making a ton of bullshit close-votes in order to *make a point*. And that's precisely what you would be doing rather than close-voting things you think should be closed. So yes, I would be suspending you for that. But you're right, it came about as a threat and that wasn't appropriate, sorry for that, I changed the comment. Of course suspensions would be preceded by corresponding warning messages and urges to desist. However, so far that's hypthetical anyway and I'm sure it will stay that way.

Comment: However for someone who sits in the glass house of repeatedly insulting other users in their comments, I'd also tone down the "bigotry and harrassment" flag abuse a little.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - you seem to be talking out your ass.   On one side you say, this kind of question isn't what we want.    When I go with that and mentioning closing questions that don't meet your "somewhat opionated and random" guidelines - you still have not clarified ANYTHING, you threaten to suspend me.   What a joke of mod behavior.    Either my "type" of question doesn't meet guidelines and all others like mine should be close too or you have proven my point.   The site is just ran by poor performing mods that close things based on their opinion, not guidelines.

Comment: I have not actually said anything about if your question is okay or not or even about the topic of this meta question yet. Yes, I admit I didn't get around the engaging and answering this meta question yet, also because it, as mentioned, mixes up quite a few issues. I was going to look further into your main site question, since it looks like it could possibly be reopened if fleshed out a little more, together with answering this meta question.

Comment: However, my interest in doing so frankly wanes with every further comment here. So far my *only* engagement in this meta discussion was based on rude comments and problematic meta behaviour and I'm getting a bit sick of that, too. I'd rather you stop those wild accusations and insults and we can concentrate on the topic of this meta question without constantly running with our arms up about what assholes the moderators (who didn't touch your question, by the way) are here or who's talking out of whose asses.